# WHERE statement with SET field

Tags: php, mysql

Situation:

Have a SET field called country with values

`('us','uk','fr','intl')`

When I go to pull the content from the db:

```
$sql  = "SELECT id, title, content "; 
$sql .= "FROM table_name "; 
$sql .= "WHERE country='us'";
```

Works fine with entries labeled only 'us' but if the entry is 'us,uk' or 'us,fr,intl' and so forth. It does not pull those. Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

```
SELECT id, title, content
FROM table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('us', country)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I admit I'm a newbie but how the heck would you know something like that?

Comment: Since I've never used the `SET` datatype, I myself didn't know the function syntax offhand.  I Googled "MySQL SET" which finds the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html  (While you're there, I recommend the "Why You Shouldn't Use SET" section.)